# What does the speaker mean/imply by saying "Huge hives all over your face is always a good look, right?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, implication

I don't think it makes sense that "huge hives on one's face make one look good", therefore I do not follow what the speaker really mean or imply in this sentence.

**My guess is:**

1 It's an irony or humor, which in fact she regretted having gone on diet giving her hives.

2 It's a fashion to have hives on face??

Could anyone help me understand this sentence please?

**The context** is:

"I" am having a conversation with "she", my sister, who is a college student now and she's really smart. We are close.

Here is the sentence:

> She looked at me, then removed the glasses. ‘You okay? You look like
>   shit.’
>
> ‘So do you.’
>
> ‘I know. I went on this stupid detox diet. It’s given me hives.’ She
>   reached a hand up to her chin.
>
> ‘You don’t need to diet.’
>
> ‘Yeah. Well . . . there’s this bloke I like in Accountancy 2. I
>   thought I might start making the effort. **Huge hives all over your
>   face is always a good look, right**?’
>
> I sat down on the bed. It was my duvet cover.
>
> *Me Before You by Jojo Moyes*

Comment: She is using irony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe she is being ironic.